# Status bar color with Pixate

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar, pixate

I just found `Pixate` to style iOS apps. But I am having a problem with it.

When I style the navigation bar (in iOS 7) with the following CSS using `Pixate`

```
navigation-bar {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(84,177,222), rgb(71,107,222));
}
navigation-bar title {
    color: white;
}
```

It does not style the status bar, which remains black. As you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot black status bar]

However when I color the Navigation Bar in the interface builder the Status Bar does get the color of the Navigation Bar. As you can see here:

[Working example with interfacebuilder http://answers.pixate.com/storage/temp/89-combined.png](http://answers.pixate.com/storage/temp/89-combined.png)

So I thought: "well I could set the color both in `CSS` and in the `Interface Builder`" but then the status bar turns black too.

Is there any way I could get this working with `Pixate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the `background-size` in addition to your background color.

```
navigation-bar {
  background-size:64px;    
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(84,177,222), rgb(71,107,222));
}
```

That works for me.